# Percentage calculus based on multiple tables in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, domo

I have two tables in sql and I need to create another table performing the calculations based on two other tables.

The first one has the sum of revenue for each Ad Unit, table name is ad_unit_table

```
SELECT
    d.`Date`,
    'App' as `Partner`,
    d.`Ad Unit`,
    sum(d.`Revenue`) as `Revenue`
from
    `d_master` as d
group by
    `Ad Unit`, `Date`
```

The other table has the sum of revenue for ALL Ad Units, table name is sum_revenue

```
SELECT
    `Date`,
    `Partner`
    `Ad Unit`,
    sum(`Revenue`) as `Sum Revenue`
from
    `ad_unit_table`
group by
    `Date`
```

Now I have to find the percentage of the revenue for each Ad Unit. So the formula is (Ad Unit Rev / Sum Rev) * 100. My code currently looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ad.`Date`,
    ad.`Partner`,
    ad.`Ad Unit`,
   (ad.`Revenue` / s.`Sum Revenue`) * 100 as `Percentage`
FROM
    `ad_unit_table` as ad
    LEFT JOIN `sum_revenue` as s ON ad.`Partner`
GROUP BY
    `Date`,
    `Ad Unit`
```

It gives me all NULLS. I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Your second query doesn't make sense.  You have columns in the `select` that are not being aggregated.

Comment: And unfortunately (unbeknownst to SQL beginners) MySQL allows such an invalid second query if running with [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) mode off (where other RDBMS's would correctly err out).

Comment: @GordonLinoff whether it makes sense or not - in the Sum Revenue I have the Revenue I am looking for. I also run queries within DOMO platform that has its own quirks.

Comment: @Strawberry your comment is irrelevant. I would gladly provide a sample of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to do `LEFT JOIN sum_revenue as s ON ad.Partner` in your last query?. I tested this construct and this creates a so called cartesian product.
All rows of the left table are combined with all the rows from the other table.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

For example:

```
 create table testing.test_a (id INT);
 create table testing.test_b (id INT);

INSERT INTO test_a VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT INTO test_b VALUES(1),(2),(3),(5);

# Resulting in a cartesian product (4x4 entries)
SELECT * FROM test_a AS a LEFT JOIN test_b AS b ON a.id;

+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    3 |    1 |
|    4 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    2 |
|    4 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    3 |    3 |
|    4 |    3 |
|    1 |    5 |
|    2 |    5 |
|    3 |    5 |
|    4 |    5 |
+------+------+

# Correctly LEFT joining test_a and test_b would be:
SELECT a.id, b.id FROM test_a AS a LEFT JOIN test_b AS b ON a.id = b.id

# Or use the USING clause to join on column from both tables with same name.
SELECT test_a.id, test_b.id FROM test_a LEFT JOIN test_b USING(id);

+------+------+
| id   | id   |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |
|    4 | NULL |
+------+------+
```

Are you sure the table `sum_revenue` has entries for all units in `ad_unit_table`. If this is not the case, some values from `sum_revenue` result in `NULL` values because of the not matching entries.
If you only want the values that match use an `INNER JOIN` instead of an `LEFT JOIN`.

Also make sure that when could the calculations. none of the values are `NULL`. Doing calculating with `NULL` values results in `NULL` values.

Example:

```
SELECT 100 / NULL;         -- Result NULL
SELECT (10 * NULL) * 100;  -- Result NULL
```

Without more information like table definitions and/or sample data this is all that I can do.